# PATH not getting exported from ~/.profile until manually sourced

Tags: ubuntu, zsh, path

I am trying to modify my PATH in ~/.profile:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8/bin
echo "Path is exported."
```

I will always login via SSH so that's why I have it in ~/.profile. I am using zsh (oh-my-zsh) as my default shell and in my ~/.zprofile I am sourcing ~/.profile:

```
source ~/.profile
```

The weird part is that when I login over SSH, I see the "Path is exported." message which means that the source statement .zprofile is working but when I echo my $PATH the '/opt/jdk1.8/bin' is missing. If I then manually source ~/.profile, the path is updated properly so I am not sure why it doesn't export the path properly when it gets sourced on login. This is all inside a vagrant box if that helps. Any ideas?

Edit: Output of zsh -ixc exit 2>&1 | grep PATH:

```
+/home/vagrant/.zcompdump:1254> _postpatcomps=( '(p[bgpn]m*|*top[bgpn]m)' _pbm '(texi(2*|ndex))' _texi '(tiff*|*2tiff|pal2rgb)' _tiff '-value-,(ftp|http(|s))_proxy,-default-' _urls '-value-,LC_*,-default-' _locales '-value-,*path,-default-'
_directories '-value-,*PATH,-default-' _dir_list '-value-,RUBY(LIB|OPT|PATH),-default-' _ruby '*/X11(|R<4->)/*'
_x_arguments 'yodl(|2*)' _yodl )
+/home/vagrant/.zshrc:56> export 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games'
+/home/vagrant/.zcompdump-vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64-5.0.2:1256> _postpatcomps=( '(p[bgpn]m*|*top[bgpn]m)' _pbm '(texi(2*|ndex))' _texi '(tiff*|*2tiff|pal2rgb)' _tiff '-value-,(ftp|http(|s))_proxy,-default-' _urls '-value-,LC_*,-default-' _locales '-value-,*path,-default-'
_directories '-value-,*PATH,-default-' _dir_list '-value-,RUBY(LIB|OPT|PATH),-default-' _ruby '*/X11(|R<4->)/*'
_x_arguments 'yodl(|2*)' _yodl )
+nvm:409> PATH=+nvm:409> nvm_strip_path /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games /bin
+nvm:409> PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
+nvm:411> PATH=+nvm:411> nvm_prepend_path /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games /home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/bin
+nvm:411> PATH=/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
+nvm:417> MANPATH=+nvm:417> nvm_strip_path /home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/opt/jdk1.8/man /share/man
+nvm:417> MANPATH=/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/opt/jdk1.8/man
+nvm:419> MANPATH=+nvm:419> nvm_prepend_path /usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/opt/jdk1.8/man /home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/share/man
+nvm:419> MANPATH=/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/opt/jdk1.8/man
+nvm:420> export MANPATH
+nvm:422> export PATH
+nvm:424> export 'NVM_PATH=/home/vagrant/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0/lib/node'
```

Comment: Something is doubtless trampling on `PATH`. What does `zsh -ixc exit 2>&1 | grep PATH` show going on?

Comment: Are you sourcing something else after `~/.profile` in `~/.zprofile`?

Comment: @thrig I added the output of that command in my question. @kos Thats the only line in my `~/.zprofile`. In my `~/.profile`, after I export my modified path, I am sourcing `~/.nvm/nvm.sh`, which might have something to do with it. I am going to try moving the path exporting to the bottom.

Comment: I moved the export to the bottom of `~/.profile` and still no luck.

Comment: What happens when you disable that `nvm` stuff? (Also, in hindsight, `grep -i path=` should catch both string `PATH` and array `path` assignments.)

Comment: I removed `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` but still same result. nvm is still in the path though so I think it gets loaded from somewhere else. Should my .bashrc be getting executed upon login?

Comment: .bashrc (aren't you using zsh?) is executed by interactive shells. When you log in via ssh, your shell is both a login shell & an interactive one, so both .profile and .bashrc should be sourced (automatically); in bash.

Comment: Ah I see, didn't know it was both interactive and login. Yes I am using .bashrc, but the only reason I asked was because thats the only other place where the nvm scripts are getting sourced.

Comment: Whoops, meant I am using zsh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. Based on @L. Levrel's comment, I added an echo statement to the .zshrc, since he said that ssh login shells are both interactive and login. And sure enough, the .zshrc gets sourced AFTER the .zprofile, and the path is being overwritten in .zshrc. Moving the export command for the Java variable to ~/.zshrc solved the problem.